# C - Error: expected expression before int

Tags: c, arguments

I'm a beginner in C. I checked the various discussion for the query I was looking for, but none of them helped. 
I wrote a code for Merge Sort and I'm getting the following errors:

1. expected expression before 'int'
2. too few arguments to function 'MergeSort'

   ```
   int *list;  //pointer to array of integers 
   int * MergeSort(int *A, int x, int y);  //function definition, the function returns a pointer to an array of integers. 

   int * MergeSort(int *A, int x, int y) //function declaration
   {
   //some code

        int size=1+y-x;
        int half=size/2;

        MergeSort(int *A, 0, half-1);   //error in this line
        MergeSort(int *A, half, y);     //error in this line

   //some code
   }
   ```

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Update: Previous error resolved.

Segmentation fault (core dumped). I don't understand the problem. Here's a link to the code I've written. 
 http://ideone.com/mHXQ66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify the type of the argument when you call a function.

So instead of

```
MergeSort(*A, 0, half - 1);
```

You do

```
// You already specified that A was a pointer in your function definition: int *A
MergeSort(A, 0, half - 1);
```

When you want to call this function, with say the `list` argument you defined at the top, you just write

```
MergeSort(list, myX, myY); // where myX and myY are defined somewhere, relating to your list
```

With regards to your function, you need some more meat in the function body. You especially need to check for the case when your array split into pieces of size 1. So add this

```
if(x - y < 2) // if run size == 1
    return;
```

Otherwise you never return! Think of when `x == y`, you will just call MergeSort(A, 0, 0) over and over again until your stack overflows.

---

**Concerning the segmentation fault**

I cannot see anything wrong with the full code you linked to. Seems pretty ok to me, but I don't have the possibility to debug your program for you. Rather, I will point you to DDD, a graphical front-end to the GDB debugger, making it A LOT more user friendly.

It can be downloaded [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), and a great debugging tutorial [can be found here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Debug/Debug.pdf). Using that you will find the error in minutes.

Comment: Right, the calling thing is clear.
Anyway, that problem is resolved. But instead I am getting a segmentation fault now. :/

Comment: The seg fault is probably due to you calling a function with wrong index arguments, for instance pointing to a segment outside of your program.

Comment: Added a section to my answer. Please accept it (and upvote) if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes I've done all the basic Merge Sort stuff. I don't understand the mistake. I'm new here, are we allowed to post full codes and ask people to check logical errors as well?

Comment: Added some more explaining to my answer. You can ask for logical errors as well - I just explained one :). Of course you can post full code, but try to trim it to make it as relevant as possible. Not lots of irrelevant fluff around it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've posted a link to the code. I guess that should suffice.

Comment: Mallika, on SO it is customary to keep to one question at a time. If you want additional help with your segfault, I suggest you start a new thread explicitly saying you need help in finding the cause of your segfault. I will add some info at the end of my answer to help you going, but I have tried inspecting and running your program and cannot see immediately where the error is. But if *the original* question is answered, I suggest you award someone the answer, as well as upvoting helpful answers. People are a lot friendlier if they see you contribute back ;)

Comment: Oh! Alright I'll start a new thread. I can't upvote yet, not enough reputation. :P anyway, thank you!

Comment: no worries, but I am sure you can link to the new thread from your question to get more people to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 MergeSort(A, 0, half-1);   //error in this line
 MergeSort(A, half, y);     //error in this line
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify the type when passing `A` as an argument, just using the values name

```
MergeSort(A, 0, half - 1);
MergeSort(A, half, y);
```